# Troubles merging two json urls

Tags: python, json, url

First of all, I am getting this error. When I try running
`pip3 install --upgrade json`
in an attempt to resolve the error, python is unable to find the module.
The segment of code I am working with can be found below the error, but some further direction as for the code itself would be appreciated.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chicago_cp.py", line 18, in <module>
    StopWork_data      = json.load(BeautifulSoup(StopWork_response.data,'lxml'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

# Define Merge
def Merge(dict1, dict2):
    res = {**dict1, **dict2}
    return res

# Open the URL and the screen name
StopWork__url = "someJsonUrl"
Violation_url = "anotherJsonUrl"

StopWork_response  = http.request('GET', StopWork__url)
StopWork_data      = json.load(BeautifulSoup(StopWork_response.data,'lxml'))

Violation_response = http.request('GET', Violation_url)
Violation_data     = json.load(BeautifulSoup(Violation_response.data,'lxml'))

dict3 = Merge(StopWork_data,Violation_data)
print (dict1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.load` expects a file object or something else with a `read` method. The `BeautifulSoup` object doesn't have a method `read`. You can ask it for any attribute and it will try to find a child tag with that name, i.e. a `<read>` tag in this case. When it doesn't find one it returns `None` which causes the error. [Here's a demo](https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/SinfulCyanCallback#main.py):

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>hi</p>", "html5lib")
assert soup.read is None
assert soup.blablabla is None

assert json.loads is not None
json.load(soup)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    json.load(soup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

If the URL is returning JSON then you don't need `BeautifulSoup` at all because that's for parsing HTML and XML. Just use `json.loads(response.data)`.